# adonis issue: error: `migration:run` is not a registered command

Tags: adonis.js

**I Have installed @adonisjs/lucid.
create a migration to use command**

> adonis make:migration task

** task code**

```
'use strict'

const Schema = use('Schema')

class TaskSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.create('tasks', table => {
      table.increments()
      table.timestamps()
      table.string('name')
      table.text('description')
      table.integer('project_id').unsigned()
      table
        .foreign('project_id')
        .references('projects.id')
        .onDelete('cascade')
    })
  }

  down() {
    this.drop('tasks')
  }
}

module.exports = TaskSchema
```

*i have run my migration to show this error*

```
error: `migration:run` is not a registered command
```

**

> i have not understand this bug. I know that if not install the
>   dependencies  @adonisjs/lucid than show this error but After I
>   installed dependencies  why the error occurred

**

Comment: you use npm or yarn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to this question

*In fact, I don’t need to install the CLI in production.
Run your server with node server.js and execute internal commands with node ace XXX.*

```
node ace migration:run --force
```

Comment: MD JAMIL AJ, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is adonis/cli.

```
npm i -g @adonisjs/cli
```

But I think the you don't really need this extra dependencies. Using [ace](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/ace#_introduction) is enough

```
node ace make:migration task
```

Comment: I installed this first time in my adonis js code to Quick Start

Comment: any command "adonis" throw this error? If u run "adonis --help", get similar error? If so I recommend to deletel node_modules folder and run npm install again

Comment: For anyone else new to AdonisJS, `adonis migration:run` can give this same error message (`error: 'migration:run' is not a registered command`) when you have accidentally deleted the `ace` file in the root of your project